# Finding the sum total of every third column between two dates in excel

Tags: excel, function, vba, date, sum

I am trying to get a certain table setup and I didn't realize when I first started it was going to be a bad setup. Many of my coworkers already use it but I need help making a formula for my excel.

I and trying to combine:

```
SUMPRODUCT(A3:Q3,--(MOD(COLUMN(A3:Q3),3)=0))
```

which is getting the sum of ever third column with :

```
=SUMIFS(A3:Q3,A1:Q1,">="&F1+1,A1:Q1,"<="&Q1)
```

where i am trying to find the sum between two dates.

I have don't many mathematical with excel and I cant seem to get it to work. Any help? I am new to excel too sorry all.

Comment: Would like to help you, but am struggling to understand what you want. You have tagged this as VBA - so are you looking to write your own customized function which can be deployed in a worksheet cell, or are you looking for a clever formula author (of which I am not one)

Comment: Either or to me. I am just trying to make it so i can get the sum of every third column between two dates in an excel sheet. Sorry if i was ambiguous on my description.

Comment: Sum every third column that has a value between two dates? Are you summing dates (i.e. you want the dates to be added together) or are you summing number values - you seem to be searching row 3 for values, but is it row 1 for dates?

Comment: Get a cell every third column column in one row between two set dates and add them all up into one value yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I and trying to combine:

```
SUMPRODUCT(A3:Q3,--(MOD(COLUMN(A3:Q3),3)=0))
```

> which is getting the sum of ever third column with :

```
   =SUMIFS(A3:Q3,A1:Q1,">="&F1+1,A1:Q1,"<="&Q1)
```

To combine those just add the extra requirements as additional arrays on the end of `SUMPRODUCT` like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A3:Q3,--(MOD(COLUMN(A3:Q3),3)=0),--(A1:Q1>=(F1+1)),--(A1:Q1<=Q1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This custom function will do something like what you want. It illustrates the basic approach in any case. Open the VBA editor (VBIDE) by hitting Alt+F11, create a new module by right clicking on the "modules" folder within the editor (use the view menu to make sure the project explorer is open), and copy and paste the following in. You should debug it yourself so you can see what it's doing by setting breakpoints or creating a calling sub (example at the bottom) so you can step through it by using F8

```
Option Explicit


Public Function THIRDCOLUMNDATESUM(ByVal colStart As Long, ByVal colEnd As Long, _
 ByVal DateMin As Date, ByVal DateMax As Date) As Double

 'returns a long sum of the numerical values in row three of every third column
 'it checks to ensure that the date (at the top of the column) is between
 'the two passed dates (DateMin and DateMax)

'Allocate for a long counter and a Double sum (in case you are working with decimals)
Dim i As Long, sum As Double

'for each column between colStart and colEnd
For i = colStart To colEnd
    'if it's the first column, or in a column divisible by three with no remainder
    If (i = 1) Or (i Mod 3 = 0) Then
        'And the date in the column header (row 1) is between (but not equal to)
        'DateMin and DateMax
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i) > DateMin And ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i) < DateMax Then
            'add the numerical value in row 3 of that column to the sum
            sum = sum + ActiveSheet.Cells(3, i).Value
        End If
    End If
'next column
Next i

THIRDCOLUMNDATESUM = sum

End Function
```

Example test sub

```
Sub Test()

THIRDCOLUMNDATESUM 1, 18, "15/1/1950", "15/01/2015"

End Sub
```

You can use it in a worksheet cell by simply typing:

`=THIRDCOLUMNDATESUM(1, 21, A1, F1)`

assuming the dates you want as your bounds are in cells A1 and F1, and you only want to look in columns A - U